# indexof array using linq except

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following two lists

```
List<String> list1 = new List<String>();
list1.Add("one");
list1.Add("two");
list1.Add("three");
list1.Add("four");
list1.Add("five");

List<String> list2= new List<String>();
list2.Add("one");
list2.Add("two");
list2.Add("three");

IEnumerable<int> indexOfUnwantedColumns;
indexOfUnwantedColumns = list1.Except(list2)
                              .Select((p, i) => new { Item = p, Index = i })
                              .Select(p => p.Index);
```

As expected this will give the index of the two items in the new list (0 and 1). I want to be able to get there index values from the original list (3 and 4)

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: How do `headers` and `placeHolders` relate to `list1` and `list2`.

Comment: My mistake, I have changed the names in the linq statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main idea is to capture the original index *before* filtering, and then check if `list2` contains each item. To be able to perform these lookups efficiently (in `O(1)` aggregated time per lookup), you should use a hashset:

```
var hashset = new HashSet<string>(list2);
var unwantedColIndexes = list1
    .Select((item, idx) => new { item, idx })  // capture the original index
    .Where(i => !hashset.Contains(i.item))     // filter using the hashset
    .Select(i => i.idx)                        // get the index only
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one simple approach:

```
IEnumerable<int> indexOfUnwantedColumns = list1
  .Select((str, index) => new {str, index} )
  .Where(x => !list2.Contains(x.str))
  .Select(x => x.index);
```

a more efficient approach on large sequences is using `Enumerable.Join`("Left Outer Join"):

```
var l1Cols = list1.Select((str, index) => new {str, index} );
var l2Cols = list2.Select((str, index) => new {str, index} );
IEnumerable<int> indexOfUnwantedColumns = 
            from c1 in l1Cols
            join c2 in l2Cols on c1.str equals c2.str into gj
            from outerJoin in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where outerJoin == null
            select c1.index;
```